# Mismatched types for returned struct (expected <K, V>, found <&K, &V>)

Tags: rust

Given the following code (which doesn't do much yet):

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::iter::FromIterator;

trait Node<K, V> {
    fn split(&self) -> Split<K, V>;
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Config {
    data_b: usize,
}

struct Split<'a, K, V> {
    left: Box<Node<K, V> + 'a>,
    right: Box<Node<K, V> + 'a>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct DataNode<K, V> {
    cfg: Config,
    children: BTreeMap<K, V>,
}

impl<K: Clone + Ord, V: Clone> Node<K, V> for DataNode<K, V> {
    fn split(&self) -> Split<K, V> {
        let data_b = self.cfg.data_b;

        Split {
            left: Box::new(DataNode {
                cfg: self.cfg.clone(),
                children: BTreeMap::from_iter(self.children.iter().take(data_b))
            }),
            right: Box::new(DataNode {
                cfg: self.cfg.clone(),
                children: BTreeMap::from_iter(self.children.iter().rev().take(data_b))
            }),
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler gives the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> lib.rs:68:9
   |
68 |         Split {
   |         ^ expected type parameter, found &K
   |
   = note: expected type `Split<'_, K, V>`
   = note:    found type `Split<'_, &K, &V>`
```

I'm pretty new to Rust so I'm not sure what's causing this. To be absolutely clear, the question I'm having is *not* about what the error message *means*. Clearly, it means that I'm not returning the right type. The question is *why* does the compiler interpret this `Split {...}` code as code that returns `Split<'_, &K, &V>` when I expect it to be `Split<'_, K, V>`. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Do you understand [*what references are*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/references-and-borrowing.html)? Do you understand how [`BTreeMap::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.iter) works? IMO, the error message is pretty straightforward — you've said you are going to return one thing but you returned something else. What piece of information is missing that we can further clarify?

Comment: I didn't say I didn't understand the error message. What I don't understand is *why* what I've written results in `Split<'_, &K, &V>`. If it has to do with a subtlety that comes with using an iterator then, yes, that's beyond my level of Rust knowledge, and I would appreciate some insight. The best I was able to do before coming here was check that return types of everything but nothing indicates references would come into play. So somehow the compiler feels compelled out of some requirement to do this and I'd like to understand why and how I can get what I want, if that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The references come from where you iterate on the child to build a new `BTreeMap`:

```
BTreeMap::from_iter(self.children.iter().take(data_b))
```

If you look at the [iterator returned by `BTreeMap::iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.13.0/collections/btree_map/struct.Iter.html), the `Item` type is:

```
type Item = (&'a K, &'a V)
```

i.e. the iterator returns pairs of references to the contents.  This makes sense, because you don't want to move items out of the map when iterating, or rely on `Copy`.

This is slightly different from e.g. `Vec::iter()`, being a pair of references rather than a reference to a pair.  This does make sense, as a reference to a pair would mean the container would have to actually contain those pairs internally (restricting the internal data structure).

The simplest thing is to clone the key and value:

```
BTreeMap::from_iter(self.children.iter()
                                 .map(|(&a, &b)| (a.clone(), b.clone()))
                                 .take(data_b))
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and for pointing towards a possible solution. You're right that it does make sense. I did check around for types in all the various methods I was using but I was misled by the docs saying `fn iter(&self) -> Iter<K, V>` so I was scratching my head. Now I know where I should have been looking.

Comment: I do a lot of clicking through types in the online documentation! You learn all sorts of things.